# How to open a port below 1024 in Cent OS for socket.io?

Tags: centos, iptables, centos5, node.js, socket

I'm trying to open port `843` in my Cent OS 5.2, I added following line to `etc\sysconfig\iptables` :

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 843 -j ACCEPT
```

and then updated my `iptables` service. I need to listen to that port in my node.js application which is running by root user via `sudo node index.js` command,  but I still get `forbidden port` error when I try establish a connection through that port.

this is what I get by running `sudo iptables -L -v` :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                     
 2811  238K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                tcp dpt:http
  112  6224 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                tcp dpt:hbci
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                tcp dpt:843
   41  2124 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                state NEW tcp multiport dports 5901:5903,6001:6003
13093   13M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   26  3584 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                        
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere                        
  109  6404 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere                                state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
 888K   80M REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

and this is outpou of `sudo netstat -ptl | grep node`:

```
tcp        0      0 *:843       *:*    LISTEN      12927/node
tcp        0      0 *:http      *:*    LISTEN      12927/node
tcp        0      0 *:10843     *:*    LISTEN      12927/node
```

and I try to listen to that port in [socket.io](http://socket.io) with this code:

```
var io          = require('socket.io').listen(
                    843,
                    {   log: false,
                        flashPolicyServer: true,
                        transports: ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-multipart', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']
                    }
                );
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    // my event listeners
});
```

Comment: Already opened on Stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065197/how-to-open-a-port-below-1024-in-cent-os-for-socket-io

Comment: Sorry didn't saw the "on hold" status for off-topic. Where do you see "forbiden port"? can you activate the socket.io logs and set log level to 3?

Comment: FWIW, your iptables configuration looks correct, and node is obviously listening on 843, so I'm guessing the problem is either internal to node, or SELinux.

Comment: @bgentil thanks for your help, problem was from client side. a firewall was blocking that port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved. all server configuration was correct, apparently a firewall in client side was blocking that port. so I am switching to [sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs) which uses the same port as http server (port 80), thus there is no risk of connection being blocked from client side.

Comment: A BIG THANKS  - SAME ISSUE WITH ME, Client side firewall was restricting to connect with socket at server on 80 port